# Can't convert HTML file to pdf with NPM WEBSHOT

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, phantomjs

Did someone ever try to convert a HTML file to pdf using nmp webshot? 
Im trying to convert a HTML film to pdf document using npm webshot but all I can get is a pdf document with a lot of padding on the right side and on the bottom. I am using a fixed size for the body of the HTML,width: 2480px;
height: 3508px, and I put the same width and height in the webshot options.

```
var options = {
    windowSize: {
        width: 2500,
        height: 3508
    },
    shotSize: {
        width: 'window',
        height: 'window'
    },
    shotOffset: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
    },
    quality: 300,
    siteType: 'html',
    renderDelay: 50,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'
};
```

This is the result I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLl0N.png

Comment: Is there any specification to use `Webshot`? I think it's more comfort for images.
you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Comment: I tried html-pdf but I get the same result :)